# Linq 'where' clause returning CS1929

Tags: c#, linq

Still learning the nuances of Linq.
Researched, but couldn't find a resolution to what I assume is an easy fix.

Edit:  As requested here is the full code block:

```
//Jboyd pull back all relative orgs
var parent =
from s in Students
where s.Id==5027
select new { 
    ID_PK = s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK == null ?
    (int) s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.ID_PK
    :
    (int) s.CaseOwnerIdAspnet_Users.User_ID_FKDYN_User_Profile.Organization_ID_FKDYN_Organization.Parent_ID_FK
    };

var orgs = 
from o in DYN_Organizations
join p in parent on o.Parent_ID_FK equals p.ID_PK
select new {ID_PK = o.ID_PK};

var unionOrgs = parent.Union(orgs) ;
```

//unionOrgs is a list of Orgs
//the below query: I need to query a bigger table where orgs are in the above list

```
var userProfilesQuery = from up in DYN_User_Profiles
where unionOrgs.Contains(up.Organization_ID_FK) //this is where the error occurs 
select up;
```

Error:
CS1929 'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains(ParallelQuery, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'

ulimately the goal is unionOrgs returns a list of orgs.  I then want to query a bigger table for any of the orgs within that list

Comment: That is because `orgs` is a collection of object with the property of `ID_PK`s. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `IQueryable<>` inherits `IEnumerable<t>` as @gilad indicated your Orgs is a collection

Comment: Do something about your class and property names. This is very hard to read (and you have to do that all the time!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orgs` is not a single instance but a collection and that is why it does not have a property of `ID_PK`. Instead use `Contains`:

```
var orgs = from o in DYN_Organizations
           join p in parent on o.Parent_ID_FK equals p.ID_PK
           select o.ID_PK;

var query = from up in userProfilesQuery
            where orgs.Contains(up.Organization_ID_FK) 
            select up;
```

See also that as you projected an anonymous object with a single field then you might as well just project the property and receive `IQueryable<int>` instead of `IQueryable<AnonymousObject>`.

Specifically for the second query, I find method syntax cleaner:

```
var query = userProfilesQuery.Where(up => orgs.Contains(up.Organization_ID_FK));
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick feedback.  With both solutions above I get this new error:

CS1929 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: int ID_PK>>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<int>(ParallelQuery<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<int>'

Comment: @JoshuaBoyd give us the whole code surrounding this, it's not possible to deduct more with what you pasted (show us what type DYN_Organisations and userProfilesQuery are and how they are declared, ideally paste the whole function)

Comment: Sorry for the continous updates. I tried to simply the code, by just extracting what I thought was relative, but had multiple request to post the full code block.  

Super appreciate the help -